# Possible generalizations of Hadamard's three line lemma

Tags: cv.complex-variables, interpolation

Let $f$ be an analytic function on a sector 
$$
S=\left\{re^{i\theta}:0<r<\infty,\; 0<\theta<\gamma<\frac{\pi}{2}\right\}
$$
with opening angle $\gamma$ at the origin. Suppose $f$ is bounded on the boundary; that is,
$$
|f(r)|\leq M_1
$$
and 
$$
|f(re^{i\gamma})|\leq M_2
$$
for all $r>0$, and $f$ satisfies some admissible growth conditions in the interior (such as polynomial growth); then Hadamard's three line lemma says that $\log\sup_{r>0}|f(re^{i\theta})|$ is a convex  function of $\theta$. In another words, we have 
$$
\sup_{r>0}|f(re^{i\theta})|\leq M_1^{1-\frac{\theta}{\gamma}}\times M_2^{\frac{\theta}{\gamma}}.
$$
I want to know if it's necessary to  assume that the given function $f$ is bounded  on the whole boundary. Especially, I'm interested to know what's the weakest assumption of the behavior of $f$ on the boundary to still guarantee the above theorem.  For example, if we change the second condition to the following
$$
|f(re^{i\gamma})|\leq M_2(1+r)^{a},
$$
for some $a>0$ (now $f$ has polynomial growth on one side ), and $f$ is still bounded on the positive real line, and satisfy the same admissible growth condition on the interior, then can we also obtain the same conclusion? If not, is there any counterexample to this?

Thanks very much for any comment.

Comment: You need to specify more precisely what "the same conclusion" is in your modified context.  Clearly $\sup_{r>0} |f(re^{i\theta})| \leq M_1^{1-\frac{\theta}{\gamma}} \times M_2^{\frac{\theta}{\gamma}}$ will no longer be true, as can be seen by inspecting the limit $\theta \to \gamma$.  On the other hand, one still has convexity of $\log \sup_{r>0} |f(re^{i\theta})|$ (if one adopts the convention that convexity is automatic when the supremum is infinite), simply by reducing the sector to the region where the sup is finite and applying the usual three lines lemma.

Comment: If instead you want $f$ to have intermediate polynomial growth on intermediate rays, then such a statement is indeed true (up to a loss of a multiplicative constant), and can be derived by dividing $f$ by a suitable multiplier designed to cancel out the polynomial growth on the $e^{i\gamma}$ ray; I recommend doing so as an instructive exercise.